# List of Array in console application C#

Tags: c#

Im working on a school project and I havent found a working syntax for the last 2 hours.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string[]> loggBook = new List<string[]>();
        string[] loggBookArray = new string[2];

        loggBookArray[0] = "1";
        loggBookArray[1] = "2";
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);
        loggBookArray[0] = "3";
        loggBookArray[1] = "4";
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);
        loggBookArray[0] = "5";
        loggBookArray[1] = "6";
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);

        foreach (string[] x in loggBook)
        {
            string s = string.Join("\n", x);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Basically what this does is printing out 5,6,5,6,5,6 when I want it to print out 1,2,3,4,5,6. I can get it to work if I use multiple string[] but I thought it would look cleaner with just a single string[]. How do I get it to be saved the way I want? Also, when they have been saved in the list, is there any way to edit the ones that have been put in the list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you keep overwriting the two elements so what you put in there last is what is printing out.

Comment: Read this about memory: http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/04/28/foundations-of-programming-pt-7-back-to-basics-memory/

Comment: Why not just generate your desired output with a simple `for` loop? Seems that the use of an array is slightly obfuscated to achieve a simple incremented list, especially if the end result is doing a `foreach` anyway.

Comment: No idea what the requirements are, but you can get your expected result with just `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 6)));`

Comment: `loggBook.Add(loggBookArray.ToArray());` should do the trick

Comment: After each add just do `loggBook = new string[2];` so you'll be dealing with 3 arrays instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use collection initializes which would make the code shorter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var loggBook = new List<string[]>
    {
        new[] {"1", "2"},
        new[] {"3", "4"},
        new[] {"5", "6"}
    };

    foreach (var x in loggBook)
    {
        var s = string.Join("\n", x);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To edit and item you could access it by index like so:

```
//Edit item (first element in the list, second in the array)
loggBook[0][1] = "0";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! We have to use the 

List<string[]> loggBook = new List<string[]>();

for the assignment, but that edit-comment helps out a ton. I was stuck on loggBook [0] and didnt realize you had to access the specific slot aswell. Thanks again!

Comment: Just be aware of the `List` and `Array` dimensions, in more complex situations it is not uncommon to try to access an index outside of a collection.
This results in index out of range exception.

Comment: also, you can do `loggBook.SelectMany(a => a).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` to print out your list

Answer (score 2):

you need to reinitialize the array after you add it otherwise you keep overwriting the same elements as the array is pointing to a specific memory address.  Arrays are objects not value types

```
        List<string[]> loggBook = new List<string[]>();
        string[] loggBookArray;

        loggBookArray = new string[] { "1", "2" };
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);
        loggBookArray = new string[] { "3", "4" };
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);
        loggBookArray = new string[] { "5", "6" };
        loggBook.Add(loggBookArray);

        foreach (string[] x in loggBook)
        {
            string s = string.Join("\n", x);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew what it did wrong, I just didnt know what I had to write in order for it to work. Do you have any tips on how to edit the list aswell? If I after this wanted to change the 4 to a 7 for example.

Answer (score -2):

you must renew string[] before add to list.

Comment: an answer should be more descriptive than a comment which this is more like